# Marked for react-native

Tags: react-native, markdown, javascript-marked

I am fetching strings with markdown from api and trying to use them in react-native project.

Is there any similar library to [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) that can be used in react-native or what is the best practice to achieve same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not have a chance to try any, but it looks like there are some libraries available, that can handle markdown

- [react-native-markdown](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-markdown)
- [react-native-markdown-view](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/react-native-markdown-view)
- [react-native-simple-markdown](https://github.com/CharlesMangwa/react-native-simple-markdown)

Comment: Went for https://github.com/CharlesMangwa/react-native-simple-markdown and working as expected.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-markdown-renderer has full common mark support. Made it because I thought all the other markdown renderers are A just a webview or B support but a verry small range of the spec

Comment: I've tried all three in some depth.  The only one that renders lists properly is `react-native-markdown-view`.  `react-native-simple-markdown` renders the list bullet in the middle instead of at the top of the list item, and the styling was also bugged.  `react-native-markdown-renderer` renders lists off the right side of the screen.  FWIW, as of Dec 6 '17, `react-native-markdown-view` is also the only lib to have merged a pull request in the last month.