# Bold text between asterix React Native

Tags: react-native, styling, text-styling

I have a RN app which communicates with my backend. In this app, there are some fields which have dynamic styling. It's formatted in a pretty standard format.

- `asterix` bold text `asterix`
- `asterix` `asterix` italic text

I want to use this string (which I get from the backend) to render an appropriately styled component. Example:

```
render("this *is bold*) = <Text> this <Text style={fontWeight: "bold"}> is bold </Text> </Text>
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: When you say standard, do you mean Markdown? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937927/marked-for-react-native

Comment: @Ben Butterworth never realized it was markdown! thanks, this is it